# Preventing duplicate objects being added to firebase back end

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question regarding preventing duplicates from being added to
 cart while using firebase as back-end.

It should be straight forward but for some reason, nothing I try is working.

```
    const { products } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {products === undefined ? (
          <p>Loading......</p>
        ) : (
          products.map(val => {
            return (
              <div key={val.id} className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-6">
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <img src={val.url} className="img-fluid" alt="Responsive" />
                    <h5 className="card-title">{val.name}</h5>
                    <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
                      {val.price}
                    </h6>
                    <button
                      className=" "
                      style={{
                        float: "right",
                        marginBottom: "1px",
                        width: "100%"
                      }}
                      onClick={() => this.submit(val)}
                    >
                      <i className="fas fa-cart-plus" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })
        )}
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: where do you have your cart? what does the submit method look like?

Comment: I used firebaseConnect..                                                                                
export default  compose(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps),
firestoreConnect(props =>[
{collection: 'carts', where:['uid', '==', props.uid ? props.uid: ''] },
]))(Cart)

Comment: so, you have a carts prop with the already added to cart items?